# yum + Protected multilib versions

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum

During yum installing , we get the following messages

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

       Protected multilib versions: nss-3.19.1-18.el7.i686 != nss-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: nspr-4.10.8-2.el7_1.i686 != nspr-4.19.0-1.el7_5.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: nss-util-3.19.1-4.el7_1.i686 != nss-util-3.36.0-1.el7_5.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-13.el7_1.i686 != nss-softokn-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64
```

what is the meaning of - protected multilib versions

how to resolve this situation?

Comment: An you also post the output of ‘rpm -q nss nspr nss-util nss-softokn’?  I suspect you have an incomplete transaction that left you with multiple copies of the same rpm and arch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yum multilib makes sure that you install the exact same version of the same program in 32bit and 64bit flavor.

Here `yum` warns you that he cannot install both

- nss-3.19.1-18.el7.i686
- nss-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64

on the same system because they don't have the exact same version number.

To solve this you have multiple options:

- investigate if you really need to install the 32bit versions of the same program on your 64bit system
- if you really need those 32bit versions; make sure `yum` has access to the exact same version numbers for each pair.
- you might need to help `yum` a bit because he will always select the very last version avaible for each package to install, so you might need to specify some version numbers manualy.

Comment: first thank you so much for the really  great answer WOW , let me ask you something , since our OS is --> 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 , then its logical that we need to remove any rpm of 32bit ( i686 ) , am I right ?

Comment: "remove ANY" seems a bit dangerous. The question here is rather: why is yum proposing to install nss 32bit while nss64bit is present? I don't really know what nss does, but if it's not crucial you can try removing all nss*i586 rpms from your system.

Comment: so please correct me if I am wrong , the best solution is to fit the rpm's version that belong to 32 bit to 64bit , is it right?  ( for example nss-3.36.0-5.el-18.el7.i686 == nss-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64

Comment: yes, that is what multilib tries to do (but probably multilib not only wants the same version numbers but also the same release numbers: 5.el-18 != el_5)